# Find combinations of size r from a set with decreasing sum value

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of numbers eg. `[100,90,80,70,60,50]` and want to find all combinations of size `r=3` but in order of decreasing sum. 
Arranging the numbers in decreasing order does not work eg.

```
(100, 90, 80) 270
(100, 90, 70) 260
(100, 90, 60) 250
(100, 90, 50) **240**
(100, 80, 70) **250**
(100, 80, 60) 240
```

How can i go about finding such a combination set with decreasing sum value.

Comment: Generate all possible subsets and store them in [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)?

Answer (score 0):

Here' the Code

```
import itertools

array = [100,90,80,70,60,50]
size = 3
answer = [] # to store all combination
order = [] # to store order according to sum
number = 0 # index of combination

for comb in itertools.combinations(array,size):
    answer.append(comb)
    order.append([sum(comb),number]) # Storing sum and index
    number += 1

order.sort(reverse=True)  # sorting in decreasing order

for key in order:
    print key[0],answer[key[1]] # key[0] is sum of combination
```

Output for the above code is

```
270 (100, 90, 80)
260 (100, 90, 70)
250 (100, 80, 70)
250 (100, 90, 60)
240 (90, 80, 70)
240 (100, 80, 60)
240 (100, 90, 50)
230 (90, 80, 60)
230 (100, 70, 60)
230 (100, 80, 50)
220 (90, 70, 60)
220 (90, 80, 50)
220 (100, 70, 50)
210 (80, 70, 60)
210 (90, 70, 50)
210 (100, 60, 50)
200 (80, 70, 50)
200 (90, 60, 50)
190 (80, 60, 50)
180 (70, 60, 50)
```

Comment: Same algorithm, but shorter code: `order = sorted(combinations(array, size), key=sum, reverse=True)`

Answer (score -1):

The first (and naive) solution is to iterate over all posible permutations, and save those sets in a min-heap. At the end just remove all sets one by one.
run time: suppose x = n choose r, so O(xlogx)

The second one is a little more complicated:
* You need to save the minimum number you found out untill now
* now you are iterating exactly like your example with one change, to know what is the next set you are moving to, you have to replace every number in the current set with the next number in the array, and replace the max option that less than the minimum you are saving. and of course set the minimum to the new minimum.
run time: O((n choose r)*r)

Comment: why not? the condition that the next step has to be less or equal will guaranty that you will always decreasing, and the maximum of all options  will guaranty you won't miss any option

Comment: "replace every number in the current set with the next number in the array" will skip over valid combinations. I doubt that is what you meant. But replacing one element is not guaranteed to find the next smaller.combination.