# Find combinations (without "of size=r") from a set with decreasing sum value using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

(Revised for clarity 02-08-2021)

This is similar to the question here:
[Find combinations of size r from a set with decreasing sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405057/find-combinations-of-size-r-from-a-set-with-decreasing-sum-value)
This is different from the answer posted in the link above because I am looking for answers without "size r=3".

I have a set (array) of numbers.
I need to have the sums of combinations of the numbers sorted from largest to smallest and show the numbers from the array that were used to get the total for that row.

Any number in the array can only be used once per row but all the numbers don't have to be used in each row as the total decreases.

If a number is not used then zero should be used as a placeholder instead so I can create a CSV file with the columns aligned.

Input Example #1 with 7 numbers in the array: [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]

Desired **Output** Example #1 format where the last number in each row is the total (sum) of the row:

```
Beginning of list

30,25,20,15,10,5,1,106
30,25,20,15,10,5,0,105
30,25,20,15,10,0,1,101
30,25,20,15,10,0,0,100
...(all number combinations in between)
30,0,0,0,0,0,0,30
0,25,0,0,0,5,0,30
...(all number combinations in between)
0,0,0,15,0,0,1,16
0,0,0,15,0,0,0,15
0,0,0,0,10,5,0,15
0,0,0,0,10,0,1,11
0,0,0,0,0,5,1,6
0,0,0,0,0,5,0,5
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1

End of list
```

Also, duplicate totals are allowed and preferred showing different combinations that have the same total (sum) of the row.
For Example #1:

```
30,0,0,0,0,0,0,30
0,25,0,0,0,5,0,30
```

For example this is one row of output based on the Input Example #1 above:

`30,25,0,0,0,5,1,61`

Last number in the row is the total. The total can also be the first number but the important thing is that the output list is sorted in descending order by the total.

Input Example #2 with 5 numbers in the array: [20,15,10,5,1]

Desired **Output** Example #2 format where the last number in each row is the total (sum) of the row:

```
Beginning of list

20,15,10,5,1,51
20,15,10,5,0,50
20,15,10,0,1,46
20,15,10,0,0,45
...(all number combinations in between)
20,0,10,0,0,30
0,15,10,5,0,30
...(all number combinations in between)
0,15,0,0,1,16
0,15,0,0,0,15
0,0,10,5,0,15
0,0,10,0,1,11
0,0,10,0,0,10
0,0,0,5,1,6
0,0,0,5,0,5
0,0,0,0,1,1

End of list
```

Input Example #1: [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]

Every row of the output should show each number in the array used only once at most per row to get the total for the row.
The rows must be sorted in decreasing order by the sums of the numbers used to get the total.

The first output row in the list would show the result of 30 + 25 + 20 + 15 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 106
The second output row in the list would show the result of 30 + 25 + 20 + 15 + 10 + 5 + 0 = 105
The third output row in the list would show the result of 30 + 25 + 20 + 15 + 10 + 0 + 1 = 101
...The rest of the rows would continue with the total (sum) of the row getting smaller until it reaches 1...
The third to last output row in the list would show the result of 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 5 + 1 = 6
The second to last output row in the list would show the result of 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 5 + 0 = 5
The last output row in the list would show the result of 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1

I started with the code provided by user [Divyanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025086/divyanshu) modified with different input numbers and the () added to the last line (but I need to use all the numbers in the array instead of size=4 as shown here):

```
import itertools

array = [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]
size = 4

answer = [] # to store all combination
order = [] # to store order according to sum
number = 0 # index of combination

for comb in itertools.combinations(array,size):
    answer.append(comb)
    order.append([sum(comb),number]) # Storing sum and index
    number += 1

order.sort(reverse=True)  # sorting in decreasing order

for key in order:
    print (key[0],answer[key[1]]) # key[0] is sum of combination
```

So this is what I need as an Input (in this example):
`[30,25,20,15,10,5,1]`

size=4 in the above code limits the output to 4 of the numbers in the array.
If I take out size=4 I get an error. I need to use the entire array of numbers.

I can manually change size=4 to size=1 and run it then size=2 then run it and so on.
Entering size=1 through size=7 in the code and running it (7 times in this example) to get a list of all possible combinations gives me 7 different outputs.
I could then manually put the lists together but that won't work for larger sets (arrays) of numbers.

Can I modify the code referenced above or do I need to use a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it as follow:

Import the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The beginning of the code as in the questions:

```
import itertools
array = [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]
size = 4

answer = [] # to store all combination
order = [] # to store order according to sum
number = 0 # index of combination

for comb in itertools.combinations(array,size):
    answer.append(comb)
    order.append([sum(comb),number]) # Storing sum and index
    number += 1

order.sort(reverse=True)  # sorting in decreasing order

for key in order:
    print (key[0],answer[key[1]]) # key[0] is sum of combination
```

The code, I think could help to obtain the final option:

```
array_len = array.__len__()
# Auxiliary to place in reference to the original array
dict_array = {}
for i in range(0,array_len):
    print(i)
    dict_array[array[i]]=i
# Reorder the previous combinations
aux = []
for key in order:
    array_zeros = np.zeros([1, array_len+1])
    for i in answer[key[1]]:
        print(i,dict_array[i] )
        array_zeros[0][dict_array[i]] = i
        # Let add the total
        array_zeros[0][array_len]=key[0]
    aux.append(array_zeros[0])
# Tranform into a dataframe
aux = pd.DataFrame(aux)
# This is to add the names to the columns 
# for the dataframe
aux.columns=array + ['total']
aux = aux.astype(int)
print(aux.head().astype(int))
   30  25  20  15  10  5  1  total
0  30  25  20  15   0  0  0     90
1  30  25  20   0  10  0  0     85
2  30  25   0  15  10  0  0     80
3  30  25  20   0   0  5  0     80
4  30  25  20   0   0  0  1     76
```

### Now generalization for all sizes

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array = [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]
array_len = array.__len__()


answer = [] # to store all combination
order = [] # to store order according to sum
number = 0 # index of combination

for size in range(1,array_len+1):
    print(size)
    for comb in itertools.combinations(array,size):
        answer.append(comb)
        order.append([sum(comb),number]) # Storing sum and index
        number += 1

order.sort(reverse=True)  # sorting in decreasing order

for key in order:
    print (key[0],answer[key[1]]) # key[0] is sum of combination


# Auxiliary to place in reference to the original array
dict_array = {}
for i in range(0,array_len):
    print(i)
    dict_array[array[i]]=i
# Reorder the previous combinations
aux = []
for key in order:
    array_zeros = np.zeros([1, array_len+1])
    for i in answer[key[1]]:
        print(i,dict_array[i] )
        array_zeros[0][dict_array[i]] = i
        # Let add the total
        array_zeros[0][array_len]=key[0]
    aux.append(array_zeros[0])
# Tranform into a dataframe
aux = pd.DataFrame(aux)
# This is to add the names to the columns
# for the dataframe
aux.columns=array + ['total']
aux = aux.astype(int)
print(aux.head().astype(int))
   30  25  20  15  10  5  1  total
0  30  25  20  15  10  5  1    106
1  30  25  20  15  10  5  0    105
2  30  25  20  15  10  0  1    101
3  30  25  20  15  10  0  0    100
4  30  25  20  15   0  5  1     96
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rafael. I'm new to programming so I'm trying to understand and follow your code.
After trying to run it in an online Python compiler I got several errors which I researched and realized in need to import

Comment: You may need to import import pandas as pd and
import numpy as np .

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rafael. New to programming so I'm trying to understand and follow your code.
I got several errors which I researched and realized I need to add these lines:
`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd`
<https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/>

This is the output I am getting:
`0
1
2
3
4
5
6
30 0
23 1
19 2
13 3
8 4
5 5
3 6
30  23  19  13  8   5   3 
0  30  23  19  13   8   5   3
> 
`
In your example the first column is an index?
I need that to be the total of the other numbers or for the total to be the last number.

Comment: Saw your comment about "import pandas as pd and import numpy as np" after I already replied.

Comment: Yes, it is and index from the pandas dataframe.

Comment: OK, but my desired output should have a total of the numbers used from the array and be sorted in descending (decreasing) order by that total value. Please let me know if I should clarify better.

Comment: But do you want the total sum as the last column too ?

Comment: Rafael, also size=4 in the original code is limiting it to only using 4 numbers in the array. If I take out size=4 from the code I get an error. I need each total to use as many numbers as are in the array if necessary. Updated the original question to clarify.

Comment: Hi @rafael, I'm using this online compiler to run the code: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/
Pasted what you have shown under "Now generalization for all sizes" and it generates a lot of extra numbers so I commented out a few print statements. 

The last few lines look promising but it stops at index 4 (total 96). Is there a way for it to continue to the total of 1 as shown above in the updated Desired Output?

Comment: .head() is just to show the the top. The variable aux is the output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rafael.
I understand about .head() being the header and the variable aux being the output.
How do we get it to show more than 6 lines of output including the header?
For this input: `[30,25,20,15,10,5,1]` the last line or row of output should be `0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1`

Comment: thank you for your help! With your code I looked up a few options for pandas, removed some lines, and it works as intended. I'll post the code and mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RafaelValero ([Rafael Valero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7127519/rafael-valero)) I was able to learn about pandas, numpy, and dataframes. I looked up options for pandas to get the desired output.

Here is the final code with some extra lines left in for reference but commented out:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array = [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]
array_len = array.__len__()

answer = [] # to store all combination
order = [] # to store order according to sum
number = 0 # index of combination

for size in range(1,array_len+1):
# Commented out line below as it was giving extra information
#    print(size)
    for comb in itertools.combinations(array,size):
        answer.append(comb)
        order.append([sum(comb),number]) # Storing sum and index
        number += 1

order.sort(reverse=True)  # sorting in decreasing order

# Commented out two lines below as it was from the original code and giving extra information
#for key in order:
#    print (key[0],answer[key[1]]) # key[0] is sum of combination

# Auxiliary to place in reference to the original array
dict_array = {}
for i in range(0,array_len):
# Commented out line below as it was giving extra information
#    print(i)
    dict_array[array[i]]=i
# Reorder the previous combinations
aux = []
for key in order:
    array_zeros = np.zeros([1, array_len+1])
    for i in answer[key[1]]:
# Commented out line below as it was giving extra information
#        print(i,dict_array[i] )
        array_zeros[0][dict_array[i]] = i
        # Let add the total
        array_zeros[0][array_len]=key[0]
    aux.append(array_zeros[0])
# Tranform into a dataframe
aux = pd.DataFrame(aux)
# This is to add the names to the columns
# for the dataframe
# Update: removed this line below as I didn't need a header
# aux.columns=array + ['total']
aux = aux.astype(int)
# Tried option below first but it was not necessary when using to_csv
# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

print(aux.to_csv(index=False,header=None))
```

**Searched references:**

Similar question:
[Find combinations of size r from a set with decreasing sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405057/find-combinations-of-size-r-from-a-set-with-decreasing-sum-value)

Pandas references:
https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-display-full-dataframe-i-e-print-all-rows-columns-without-truncation/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Online compiler used:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

**Output using Input Example #1 with 7 numbers in the array: [30,25,20,15,10,5,1]:**

```
30,25,20,15,10,5,1,106
30,25,20,15,10,5,0,105
30,25,20,15,10,0,1,101
30,25,20,15,10,0,0,100
30,25,20,15,0,5,1,96
30,25,20,15,0,5,0,95
30,25,20,0,10,5,1,91
30,25,20,15,0,0,1,91
30,25,20,0,10,5,0,90
30,25,20,15,0,0,0,90
30,25,0,15,10,5,1,86
30,25,20,0,10,0,1,86
30,25,0,15,10,5,0,85
30,25,20,0,10,0,0,85
30,0,20,15,10,5,1,81
30,25,0,15,10,0,1,81
30,25,20,0,0,5,1,81
30,0,20,15,10,5,0,80
30,25,0,15,10,0,0,80
30,25,20,0,0,5,0,80
0,25,20,15,10,5,1,76
30,0,20,15,10,0,1,76
30,25,0,15,0,5,1,76
30,25,20,0,0,0,1,76
0,25,20,15,10,5,0,75
30,0,20,15,10,0,0,75
30,25,0,15,0,5,0,75
30,25,20,0,0,0,0,75
0,25,20,15,10,0,1,71
30,0,20,15,0,5,1,71
30,25,0,0,10,5,1,71
30,25,0,15,0,0,1,71
0,25,20,15,10,0,0,70
30,0,20,15,0,5,0,70
30,25,0,0,10,5,0,70
30,25,0,15,0,0,0,70
0,25,20,15,0,5,1,66
30,0,20,0,10,5,1,66
30,0,20,15,0,0,1,66
30,25,0,0,10,0,1,66
0,25,20,15,0,5,0,65
30,0,20,0,10,5,0,65
30,0,20,15,0,0,0,65
30,25,0,0,10,0,0,65
0,25,20,0,10,5,1,61
30,0,0,15,10,5,1,61
0,25,20,15,0,0,1,61
30,0,20,0,10,0,1,61
30,25,0,0,0,5,1,61
0,25,20,0,10,5,0,60
30,0,0,15,10,5,0,60
0,25,20,15,0,0,0,60
30,0,20,0,10,0,0,60
30,25,0,0,0,5,0,60
0,25,0,15,10,5,1,56
0,25,20,0,10,0,1,56
30,0,0,15,10,0,1,56
30,0,20,0,0,5,1,56
30,25,0,0,0,0,1,56
0,25,0,15,10,5,0,55
0,25,20,0,10,0,0,55
30,0,0,15,10,0,0,55
30,0,20,0,0,5,0,55
30,25,0,0,0,0,0,55
0,0,20,15,10,5,1,51
0,25,0,15,10,0,1,51
0,25,20,0,0,5,1,51
30,0,0,15,0,5,1,51
30,0,20,0,0,0,1,51
0,0,20,15,10,5,0,50
0,25,0,15,10,0,0,50
0,25,20,0,0,5,0,50
30,0,0,15,0,5,0,50
30,0,20,0,0,0,0,50
0,0,20,15,10,0,1,46
0,25,0,15,0,5,1,46
30,0,0,0,10,5,1,46
0,25,20,0,0,0,1,46
30,0,0,15,0,0,1,46
0,0,20,15,10,0,0,45
0,25,0,15,0,5,0,45
30,0,0,0,10,5,0,45
0,25,20,0,0,0,0,45
30,0,0,15,0,0,0,45
0,0,20,15,0,5,1,41
0,25,0,0,10,5,1,41
0,25,0,15,0,0,1,41
30,0,0,0,10,0,1,41
0,0,20,15,0,5,0,40
0,25,0,0,10,5,0,40
0,25,0,15,0,0,0,40
30,0,0,0,10,0,0,40
0,0,20,0,10,5,1,36
0,0,20,15,0,0,1,36
0,25,0,0,10,0,1,36
30,0,0,0,0,5,1,36
0,0,20,0,10,5,0,35
0,0,20,15,0,0,0,35
0,25,0,0,10,0,0,35
30,0,0,0,0,5,0,35
0,0,0,15,10,5,1,31
0,0,20,0,10,0,1,31
0,25,0,0,0,5,1,31
30,0,0,0,0,0,1,31
0,0,0,15,10,5,0,30
0,0,20,0,10,0,0,30
0,25,0,0,0,5,0,30
30,0,0,0,0,0,0,30
0,0,0,15,10,0,1,26
0,0,20,0,0,5,1,26
0,25,0,0,0,0,1,26
0,0,0,15,10,0,0,25
0,0,20,0,0,5,0,25
0,25,0,0,0,0,0,25
0,0,0,15,0,5,1,21
0,0,20,0,0,0,1,21
0,0,0,15,0,5,0,20
0,0,20,0,0,0,0,20
0,0,0,0,10,5,1,16
0,0,0,15,0,0,1,16
0,0,0,0,10,5,0,15
0,0,0,15,0,0,0,15
0,0,0,0,10,0,1,11
0,0,0,0,10,0,0,10
0,0,0,0,0,5,1,6
0,0,0,0,0,5,0,5
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
```